How to enable HTTP Basic Auth?
Due to having a reverse proxy in front of my SharePoint server, I would like to use HTTP Basic Auth instead of NTLM auth. (I know credentials are transmitted in plain then but I am using SSL and the connection between reverse proxy and Sharepoint is dedicated and secure).
I have enabled Basic Authentication (and disabled everything else) in IIS, exactly like this:

However, when I now log in with my account as before (Note: local user account, added via description from How to add local users to a site collection in sharepoint2013, while server is in Workgroup) , then I either get "Sorry, something went wrong, File not found" or "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.".
Is there anything else besides the IIS configuration that needs to be done?
